# Finished Real Analysis (baby Rudin syllabus), what to read next?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, education, advice

My question is more of a strategic type.

I have recently finished learning about most of the topics in baby Rudin (PMA), but from a different textbook, at my school.

As you can imagine, I haven't mastered those topics yet since I have only done the assigned problems and exercises.

Now, I would like to seek advice about what to do next? My goal is to continue learning Analysis.

I was thinking of reading the entire PMA and doing most, if not all, exercises from it before I move on to Real and Complex Analysis (RCA) by Rudin.

Should I spend some time (perhaps a year) doing PMA? Should I do a little bit of PMA on the side and RCA alongside with it? Or should I just move on to RCA altogether?

And, lastly, would you advise a book other than Rudin? I don't mind the terse and dry nature of Rudin especially because I have heard it contains really good exercises.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want more analysis? Or do you want to branch out? Depends on your answer to this question.

Comment: More analysis. Measure theory, functional analysis, Banach spaces, harder problems, etc.

Comment: If you like Rudin, I would go to Rudin's RCA next.

Comment: How would you compare RCA with Real Analysis by Folland?

Comment: calculus on manifolds by spivak

Comment: @DonlansDonlans I think knowing complex is kinda mandatory for manifolds.

Comment: For complex is Rudin's PMA and RCA enough?

Comment: @Sunny For now, pretty much.